# Are there other mailloop like software?

Tags: bulk-email

I used to use mailloop to do mass mailing and I am happy. Now it's no longer supported.

What other program we can use to send mass mail? I also need autoresponder, series autoresponder (people sign up and get 5 email 1 day each).

Any other thing like that?

Basically I need software that:

1. Capture user's email and their first name
2. Send mail merge to those users
3. Support auto responder

Should I just use mail chimp service?

Comment: updated. Why I can't vote to reopen?